# Database migration from MariaDB to PostgreSQL for materialized view

Tags: mysql, postgresql, unicode, database-migration, materialized-views

I have been using MariaDB for my company. The problem of MariaDB is that I doesn't support materialized views. Although Flexviews support materialized views, it has a problem as follows. 
When the file '**b_table.sql**' has a view definition of

```
Create table matered_view AS
Select timestampdiff(YEAR,`m`.`birthday`,curdate()) AS `age`
From `transDB`.`members` `m` ...
```

A utility (convert.php) of Flexviews can be used as follows.

```
$ php convert.php transDB < b_table.sql > mem_mv.sql
```

However, in **mem_mv.sql**  you would find

```
CALL  flexviews.add_expr(@mvid, 'COLUMN', 'timestampdiff(YEAR,m.birthday,curdate )', 'age');
```

Here checkout '**curdate**', it should have been "**curdate()**".
It also has many other problems I found extremely hard to solve.

So, to migrate our DBMS from MariaDB to PostgreSQL which support materialized view better, I'm pursuing two step procedure where step 1 is to restore the MariaDB instance onto MySQL DBMS, and  step 2 is to use this module to convert MySQL to PostgreSQL -

[philipsoutham/py-mysql2pgsql](https://github.com/philipsoutham/py-mysql2pgsql)

But, in the second step while I execute following command on my guest OS Ubuntu 16_4, I had this error -

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ub144' in position 60: ordinal not in range(128).
```

And the migration process interrupted in the middle -- still a few tables created on the PostgreSQL side successfully. Actually, Korean characters are used for the table column descriptions/comments in MariaDB, probably that caused the error. Does anyone have a suggestion on my issue?

Comment: Answer is not so simple because it depends on more factors. We use both databases - every for a good reason. MySQL/MariaDB for our web widget with very high reads ratio and PostgreSQL for heavy analytical queries over TBs of data with advanced window functions. So you have to consider the whole picture.

Comment: Sometimes it is better to write the SQL yourself, rather than depend on a 3rd party package.

Answer (score 0):

My issue settled down completely.

That is, 
for the "**UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode**" problem, I embedded these 3 lines of code for the relevant python source file.

```
import sys 
reload(sys) 
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

While I reach above solution, I referred below issue on github (specifically elkan1788's comment).

https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/2771

After the obstacle was overcome, I encountered another type of issue of "**UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character... ordinal not in range(256)**". It was solved by changing a part of postgres_writer.py in mysql2pgsql directory as follows.

```
comments.append('COMMENT ON TABLE %s is %s;' % (table.name, 
QuotedString(table.comment).getquoted()))

==>

comments.append('COMMENT ON TABLE %s is %s;' % (table.name, 
QuotedString(table.comment.encode('utf-8')).getquoted()))
```

When I do that, I refered to the Lukasa's comment on this issue -

https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1822

Then, I was able to migrate 40 something MariaDB tables finally to PostgreSQL tables by one command(**py-mysql2pgsql**).